# Insert worksheet row based on given relative range row index vba

Tags: vba, row, cell, insertion

What I'm trying to do is insert a row in a particular spot in an Excel range using VBA.  I scan the range to find out what row the string "Administration" first appears on and then would like to insert a row directly above.  The code below works.  But it only inserts a row to my Range, not to the entire work sheet, which messes up the position of some other tables further down on the same worksheet.  It would be good to figure out a way to select the entire row, so that everything further down on the worksheet gets relocated too, not just the stuff in the range.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

```
Sub insertRow(Name As String)
    Dim Rw, target As Range
    Dim insertRowNum As Integer

    Set target = ActiveSheet.Range("Table")

    'Determine proper insertion row index.  Goal is to insesrt new project right
    'before Administration'

    insertRowNum = -1 'Flag to see if loop finds "Administration" in any of the cells"
    For Each Rw In target.Rows
        If target.Cells(Rw.Row, 1) = "Administration" Then
            insertRowNum = Rw.Row
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    'Check to see if "Administration" was found'
    If insertRowNum = -1 Then
        insertRowNum = target.Rows.Count
    End If

    'Insert Blank Row
    target.Rows(insertRowNum).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
target.Rows(insertRowNum).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

try

```
Range("A" & insertRowNum).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Comment: Good deal, that worked.  One more question.  When you do Range("A" & insertRowNum) what does the "A" do?

Comment: @user1707675 "A" is just column "A", it could be replaced by B C D etc. because the entire row is being selected it doesn't matter. But range requires a column argument so something needs to be there

Comment: Oops spoke too soon.  My insertRowNum index is a relative address that captures the row number in the range, with respect to the top of the range.  So, if my range isn't at the top of the worksheet, the insertRowNum index won't be the same as the absolute row index on the worksheet.  For example, if there are two blank rows at the top of the sheet, before my table begins, insertRowNum may get assigned as 5, when I really want to insert on the 7th row of the worksheet.

Comment: @user1707675 ok, try this: `target(insertRowNum, 1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove`

Comment: I got an undefined variable error for, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove, but I just deleted that and it seemed to work fine.  That was just left over from a macro I recorded any way, so I never knew what it actually did.  Thanks.

Comment: if my or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Done.  I'm a little new to stack exchange, so I didn't know you could do that.  Thanks for the tip.